# Simplified summation sign

Tags: calculus

Assuming I have a sum of values:

$$\sum_{k=1}^K{x_{k,i}}$$

Am I allowed to re-write it like this:

$$\sum^k{x_{k,i}}$$

I am sure I have seen this before, but cannot find any example now...

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I need to indicate that the sum only refers to $k$, not $i$.

I wrote an expression like this in my thesis, which of course is not useful:

$$\sum_{k=1}^k{x_{k,i}}$$

I should have introduced an upper limit paramater $K$ and not use $k$. However, I am only allowed to make minimum changes to the formula, and are now trying to fix it...

2nd EDIT:

Probably another stupid question, but I am simply confused. In case of the summation of a product like this, do I need brackets to make sure that the product in summed, and not only $a_{h,i}$?

$$\sum_{k=1}^K{a_{h,i}\cdot x_{k,i}}$$

Comment: I have never seen the notation that you are trying to introduce, but every notation is allowed in mathematics if you define it before using it. In this case, though, I would stick to the usual notation, because yours doesn't really simplify things significantly.

Comment: You can use $\sum$ or $\sum\limits_k$ when the range is obvious from the context. But $k$ above like $\sum\limits^k$ isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often authors go from

$$\sum_{i=a}^b \mathrm{whatever}$$ to $$\sum_i \mathrm{whatever}$$ to cut down on space, so yes, you can do this. In fact, you can do anything, even if prominent authors don't do it. This is mathematics, not North Korea. Also, to clarify what's going on, you could say "bind $i$ to the set $\{a,\ldots,b\}$" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the way I have seen it.

Comment: Do you know of any example where this is used? E.g. a paper or an online book?

Comment: @Aki, now that I think about it, I can't recall any actual publications I've seen this in. But it's all over certain problem sheets I've received over the years from combinatorics and probability theory subjects. It's definitely a thing.

Comment: I pick up a random book 2 feet from my face, flip to a random page and find the author use the notation $\sum\limits_{n}$ for some sum. So it is not that uncommon as long as you notify the reader ahead of time.

Comment: I tried to do the same in my (maybe simpler) books, but nothing. I think I recall it being used when there is a double sum with indices i and j.

Comment: @Aki The random book I refer to is Flajolet and Sedgewick's "Analytic combinatorics". It didn't simplify the summation indices in every sum. In subjects where non-trivial arrangement of sums is needed, one might stop insisting of accuracy of notation but concentrate on high level structure of the sum.